# How to Run Terminal as Administrator on Mac Pro

Tags: node.js, git, macos, cordova

I am using a Mac for the first time and need to run Terminal as an admin. I have installed NodeJs and Git and want to download Phone Gap/Corova but when I try to install Cordova, it comes back with an error saying I should be an admin when running the terminal. How do I open a command prompt in terminal as an admin to the Mac Pro?

Comment: This is probably being closed as off-topic... You don't want to open a terminal as an admin, you want to use the `sudo` command. See here for details: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/how-do-i-run-terminal-in-sudo-mode http://guides.macrumors.com/sudo https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html

Answer (score 108):

This is not Windows, you do not "run the Terminal as admin". What you do is you run commands in the terminal as admin, typically using [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo):

```
$ sudo some command here
```

Comment: To entirely switch over to an admin session, you typically use `su`. This may require some specific permission configuration though before you can use that. You should stick to `sudo` unless and until you know exactly what you're doing. Get familiar with UNIX system security.

Comment: while installing few of the packages in npm it won't work because you need to use sudo for every command to avoid that do this once `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/` and the subsequent commands don't need sudo keyword.

Answer (score 65):

To switch to root so that all subsequent commands are executed with high privileges instead of using `sudo` before each command use following command and then provide the password when prompted.

`sudo -i`

User will change and remain root until you close the terminal. Execute `exit` commmand which will change the user back to original user without closing terminal.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Helpful. Thanks :-)

Comment: In the old days we just used `su` (enter). Today that returns `su:Sorry` even though the password was correct! ;-) Thankfully found this and it worked! So `sudo -i` instead of `su`.

Answer (score 12):

search for terminal
after opening the termincal type

```
su <admin-user-name>   //su - switch user
```

enter and then give the admin password
then run your sudo commands e.g:

```
sudo open MySQLWorkbench.app
```

Comment: Yours is an important answer that so many others left out - a normal user will get the `"not in sudoers"` message unless `switch user` is performed first. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 5):

You can run a command as admin using

```
sudo <command>
```

You can also switch to root and every command will be run as root

```
sudo su
```

Answer (score 3):

Add **sudo** to your command line, like:

```
$ sudo firebase init
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, all of the above solutions require to be a local admin already (or to be member of the sudoers list). I think the questioner needs a way to switch from currently non-admin/non-sudoer user to an admin-account.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/joeadmin
sudo dscl . -create /Users/joeadmin UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . -create /Users/joeadmin RealName "Joe Admin" 
sudo dscl . -create /Users/joeadmin UniqueID "510"
sudo dscl . -create /Users/joeadmin PrimaryGroupID 20
sudo dscl . -create /Users/joeadmin NFSHomeDirectory /Users/joeadmin
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/joeadmin password 
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership joeadmin
```

press enter after every sentence

Then do a:

```
sudo reboot
```

Change joeadmin to whatever you want, but it has to be the same all the way through. You can also put a password of your choice after password.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, later I came to know I need to switch user(using su command) to an admin user. After entering the password, I was able to execute the command successfully.

```
MGCXXXXXXXXD6N:~ username$ su <admin_user> 
Password: ******
bash-3.2$ _________Give your command here. It works_________________
```