# Invalid syntax with Django manage.py createsuperuser remote Terminal Mac

Tags: python-3.x, django, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to create a superuser on a remote django server. I am running a Mac.

On two separate terminals ([not within VSCode or any IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768508/python-manage-py-createsuperuser-error)) I have run the following code using `ssh` and `sftp`:

```
cd my_dir/src
ls                                 # to confirm manage.py is present
python manage.py createsuperuser 
python3 manage.py createsuperuser 
sudo python manage.py createsuperuser
sudo python3 manage.py createsuperuser
```

On `ssh`, the `python` commands result in:

```
File "manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

On `ssh`, the `python3` commands result in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

On `sftp`, both `python` and `python3` commands result in `Invalid command.`

I have also tried:

- `python manage.py shell` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095557/django-manage-py-createsuperuser-not-accepting-username))
- `sudo -i` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700746/how-to-run-terminal-as-administrator-on-mac-pro))

Any other ideas? Thank you in advance!

*Edit: It turned out there was an additional Docker container running on the server, which was why none of the above commands were working.*

Comment: It looks like Django is not installed in the current Python environment. You proberbly need to active the respective virtual environment (e.g. with `source venv/bin/activate`). Btw. `sudo` does not work here (or will not do what you want).

Comment: Thank you! Just figured out the issue here. It turned out the remote server had a docker container running that I wasn't aware of. After knowing that I was able to access it as intended. I'll update the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new question to better reflect that this was an issue with Docker: [How to create a python superuser within a remote docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278417/how-to-create-a-python-superuser-within-a-remote-docker-container/72278772#72278772)

In the mean time, here is the code that did end up fixing the issue:

```
ssh <remote_address>
cd <application_dir>
cd src
docker ps                               # to determine that docker was present.
docker exec -it <container_id> ls src   # to confirm manage.py is present
docker exec -it <container_id> sh
cd src
python manage.py createsuperuser
```