# How to create a python superuser within a remote docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ssh

I've ssh'd into a remote server and need to enter a running docker container and add a superuser.

I can run `docker exec -it <container_id> ls` and see the contents of the docker container (`/bin`, `/dev`, `docker-entrypoint.sh` etc).

From here, how do I run my python command `python manage.py createsuperuser`?

When I try `docker exec -it <container_id> python manage.py createsuperuser` I get the following error:

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

When I try `docker exec -it <container_id> sh python manage.py createsuperuser`, I get the following error:

`sh: can't open 'python': No such file or directory`

Comment: Assuming Python is, in fact, installed in the container, you'll can use the full path name (e.g., /usr/bin/python or whatever the correct path is) until you update the appropriate `PATH` variable to include the correct directory.

Comment: Hmm so I don't see python within `docker exec -it 798f637329c1 ls usr/bin`

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the image's Dockerfile and any other source code necessary to demonstrate the issue?  (Do you know that the image is actually Python-based?)

Comment: Man alive. Found out the problem. I was provided the wrong container name. @chepner's comment helped diagnose the issue though, because the container I had didn't have python installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of my problem was an incorrect container id. Answering this question to list out the working steps, even though @chepner's comment helped diagnose the issue.

```sh
ssh <remote_address>
cd <application_dir>
cd src
docker ps               # to identify the correct container ID
docker exec -it <container_id> ls src   # to confirm manage.py is present
docker exec -it <container_id> sh
cd src
python manage.py createsuperuser
```